# Add wordpress filter for a custom field to add a dynamic value

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to add a dynamic value to a custom field in wordpress.
I do not want to use update_post_meta() because it is a dynamic value that I want to add every time when the post is loaded ..

The custom field is tm_video_file, and retrieved with get_post_meta().
This will return a URL, I beed to append a query string to it.

I am trying to hook a function that will change the value of "tm_video_file", but without success.

```
// URL will be called as:
get_post_meta($post_id, 'tm_video_file', true);

// I try to add a filter for these meta data
add_filter('get_post_metadata', array($this,'add_hash_key'),1,4);

// And try to append the tm_video_file value here:
public function add_hash_key ($meta_value, $post_id, $meta_key, $single ) {

    if($meta_key == 'tm_video_file')  {
        var_dump($meta_value); // ALWAYS NULL ???
        var_dump($post_id);
        var_dump($meta_key);
        var_dump($single);
}

return $meta_value.'?hash=something-dynamic-here';

}
```

**UPDATE:**
I have found out some information on the net, and I think I am a bit closer to the solution:

```
public static function add_hash_key($meta_value, $object_id, $meta_key, $single) {

if ($meta_key == 'tm_video_file') {
            $meta_type = 'post';
            $meta_cache = wp_cache_get($object_id, $meta_type . '_meta');
            if ( !$meta_cache ) {
                $meta_cache = update_meta_cache( $meta_type, array( $object_id ) );
                $meta_cache = $meta_cache[$object_id];
            }

            if ( isset($meta_cache[$meta_key]) ) {
                if ( $single ) {
                    $meta_value = maybe_unserialize( $meta_cache[$meta_key][0] );
                } else {
                    $meta_value = array_map('maybe_unserialize', $meta_cache[$meta_key]);
                }
            }
            // At this point $meta_value contains the right data!
            $meta_value .=  '?Hash-Here';
            return array($meta_value); //
        }
    }
```

In wordpress file meta.php there is a function called:
get_metadata()
This will apply filters, and returns the value in the end:

```
    $check = apply_filters( "get_{$meta_type}_metadata", null, $object_id, $meta_key, $single );
    if ( null !== $check ) {
        if ( $single && is_array( $check ) )
            return $check[0];
        else
            return $check;
    }


//For some reason $check is ALWAYS null .. ? But the filter function did run for sure..
```